# Points in the 4326 coordinate system are not projecting correctly onto the 3857 coordinate system

Tags: qgis

I have imported two layers into QGIS: a series of points in the 4326 coordinate system and a google hybrid tile background in the 3857 coordinate system.

I have On the Fly projection enabled with the project coordinate system set to 3857, but my points in the 4326 coordinate system on not projecting into the correct location on the 3857 coordinate system.

[image: Misplaced Projection]

**Example point coordinates:**

Latitude -> 33.2139961833333
Longitude -> -86.7717682

**Layer info**
[image: Cell Test Points]

[image: Google Hybrid Background]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your points are showing up Antarctica, your lon/lat coordinates have been reversed somehow

[Antarctica](https://www.google.com.au/maps/place/86%C2%B046'18.4%22S+33%C2%B012'50.4%22E/@-84.9995661,33.2139962,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d-86.7717682!4d33.2139962)

Longitude -> 33.2139961833333
Latitude -> -86.7717682

[Alabama](https://www.google.com.au/maps/place/33%C2%B012'50.4%22N+86%C2%B046'18.4%22W/@33.2139962,-86.7739569,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d33.2139962!4d-86.7717682)

Latitude -> 33.2139961833333
Longitude -> -86.7717682

Comment: Are you sure? I've double checked on multiple sources and Latitude ->33.2139961833333, Longitude -> -86.7717682 is just south of Birmingham, AL. Google maps which you linked, takes latitude first, then longitude: https://support.google.com/maps/answer/18539?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en

Comment: The coordinates were flipped when creating the point geography object in SQL. The documentation calls out latitude, but then specifies to use the x-coordinate. The x-coordinate would be the longitudinal line value as you move laterally across the map. I was just confused because I figured the latitude value would be the value of the latitude line - like when entering the coordinates in google maps.